# How to sum values in a column based on a given condition using Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'factory': ['kerala', 'kerala', 'kerala', 'delhi', 'delhi', 'goa', 'goa'],
               'plant': ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
               'market': ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
               'product': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
               'BP4-2023': [4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5],
               'RE4-2023': [7, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8],
               'BP5-2023': [4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5],
               'RE5-2023': [7, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8]})
```

And I want to get the output dataframe like below:

```
  factory    plant   market product  BP4-2023  RE4-2023 BP5-2023  RE5-2023
0 TOTAL                                 
1   A                                15        23       15        23
2   B                                13        22       13        22
3   C                                5         8        5         8
```

Input dataframe will be dynamic(BP and RE columns).`BP` and `RE` columns will vary based on months and year.In this `A`,`B`,`C` are product names.Extra products will come,at that time that products will also be added in the output dataframe.

How can I get the below output.Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Try: `df.drop(columns='factory').groupby('product', as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: how to keep remaining columns blank like in my expected output@Corralien

Comment: `df.assign(factory='').groupby('product', as_index=False).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`. E.g. for your problem,

```py
df.groupby(['product']).sum()
```

Will produce the following output:

```
         BP4-2023  RE4-2023  BP5-2023  RE5-2023
product                                        
A              15        23        15        23
B              13        22        13        22
C               5         8         5         8
```

If you want to reuse it you can also wrap it into a function, like so:

```py
In []: def group_sum(df, column):
         print(df.groupby([column]).sum())


In []: group_sum(df, 'product')
         BP4-2023  RE4-2023  BP5-2023  RE5-2023
product                                        
A              15        23        15        23
B              13        22        13        22
C               5         8         5         8

In []: group_sum(df, 'factory')
         BP4-2023  RE4-2023  BP5-2023  RE5-2023
factory                                        
delhi          10        15        10        15
goa            10        16        10        16
kerala         13        22        13        22
```

Comment: how to keep remaining columns blank like in my expected output@worreby

Comment: @AbinBenny as far as I know that doesn't work if the columns are empty with `groupby`. If you add values to the columns they will be kept though.